# How to align headers on Vuetify v-data-table

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, html-table, vuetify.js

I have a weird problem with my header on my table, some titles are align to the top but others don´t, i tried everything even align: 'left', but it did not work out, here is a picture of my problem

[image]

And my code is this:

*Table:

```
<v-data-table :headers="header_data" :items="finalData" :search="search" u/click:row="showAlert">
                <template v-slot:item.aum="{ item }">
                    {{formatNumber(item.aum)}}
                </template>
            </v-data-table>
```

And the data for the header:

```
header_data: [
                { text: 'Name', value: 'fund', align: 'start' },
                { text: 'Ticker', value: 'ticker', align: 'start' },
                { text: 'Asset Class', value: 'assetclass', align: 'start' },
                { text: 'Provider', value: 'issuer', align: 'start' },
                { text: 'Geographic Focus', value: 'region', align: 'start' },
                { text: 'Investment focus', value: 'focus', align: 'start' },
                { text: 'AUM (USD)', value: 'aum', align: 'start' },
            ]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is usually caused by the inclusion of the `sortable` icon (`sortable` is on by default), possibly in conjunction with not setting a `width`. Each are properties that can be set in, your case, `header_data`.

You could:

- Remove sorting where it isn't needed with `sortable: false` in `header_data`
- Add a fixed `width` in `header_data` where appropriate
- Utilize the `header` or `header.<name>` slots (e.g. to wrap the text and icon in a div and use some of the built-in CSS flexbox related classes)
- Create some custom CSS

The first two options are easiest, provided you're content with the constraints they provide. The custom slot option, i.e. `header.<name>` (see the [docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables) in the slots section of the API) is pretty easy to implement, even on a cell by cell basis.

Comment: It Worked!, i just put a width prop on one of the headers, thanks

Answer (score 12):

I didn't want to have to set a fixed width, so as an example of how to fix this with CSS:

```css
.v-data-table-header th {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Credit [this comment](https://github.com/vuetifyjs/vuetify/issues/10164#issuecomment-601642148).